# PHP - array_map 2 columns and remove duplicate rows by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-map

I have the following array dynamically generated from an external API:

```
$purchases = array(
    array('product_id' => 7, 'receipt' => R13D13),
    array('product_id' => 5, 'receipt' => Y28Z14),
    array('product_id' => 7, 'receipt' => R02310),
    array('product_id' => 5, 'receipt' => E11403)
);
```

Desired output:

```
$purchases_new = array(
    array('product_id' => 7, 'receipt' => R13D13),
    array('product_id' => 5, 'receipt' => Y28Z14)
);
```

Due to the nature of the API I have only been able to pull data using array_map:

```
$purchases_unique = array_unique(
    array_map(function($pid){ return $pid['product_id']; }, $purchases)
);
print_r($purchases_unique);
```

Outputs

```
array((array[251] => 7) array([252] => 5))
```

Output completely not what I want :( How to array_map 2 columns `product_id'` and `receipt` and remove duplicate rows based on `product_id`?

I want to achieve the following:

1. `array_map` both columns? (`product_id` and `receipt`)
2. Remove `product_id` duplicates rows based on `product_id` key?

Comment: 2) in your case why should those example win?

Comment: @Goikiu sorry I don't understand your question? If you are referring to the array_map code example I gave, it is an example. There is probably a much better solution which is why I posted here :)

Comment: I didn't understand your rules to remove duplicated data. Why you are picking the first occurrence of `product_id` 7 (R13D13) and the second for `product_id` 5 (E11403)?

Comment: @Caconde so basically each row is a product purchase order. As you will see 'product_id' 5 and 'product_id' 7 each have two occurrences. I only want to display one occurrence per product, otherwise the end user will see the same products twice. It does not matter if it's the first or last occurrence, it just needs to have unique products and show 'receipt' values. Hope that make sense.

Comment: I have changed the desired output as the previous output was confusing people.

Comment: @ianhman if you can have only the last unique id you can do it one-liner with `array_column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first occurrence use @TheFirstBird answer. If you want the last occurrence you can do it simpler buy using `array_column` and `array_values` as:

```
$newArr = array_values(array_column($purchases, null, "product_id"));
```

Notice the second argument of `array_column` is null meaning take the entire element.

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/98I9h)

References: [array-column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [array-values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you're looking for:
Just adds the unique product_ids (with receipt) to a new array:

```
$purchases_new = array_reduce($purchases, function($acc, $p) {
    if(!in_array($p['product_id'], array_column($acc, 'product_id'))) {
        $acc[] = $p;
    }
    return $acc;
}, []);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'product_id' => 7,
    'receipt' => 'R13D13',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'product_id' => 5,
    'receipt' => 'Y28Z14',
  ),
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU/dSsMwFL7vUxwhkBRy0awThW7zRl/AOy0lhDSjAZceskYR2bPXNK5YFQVzEXLyne8POxzHzQ12mGUEg9edOpojbEF5r15ZBucHRd@3QQ/SthS2O7jiQL3RxuKQZnovyltR0pz/Srn8TnlYXT@K9V@Uny7FqhTFv1zuhFgXMViWV8uK0pmXuab0JkoY9oly2AenB9s7RpTWHAjm8BZNAeyeXVgnP9wJ1ssADT8L6v4pHGbuciPPZ53pTHjdxBgEq/R5Src3Q/AuoVV24lA3U/Zn5WUbDsjSztcmsdw4vgM)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment `It does not matter if it's the first or last occurrence`, you could use a `foreach` and create a `$result` array for the non duplicates.

For every iteration, use the `product_id` as the array key and check if it already has been set.

If it is not, then add it.

```
$purchases = array(
    array('product_id' => 7, 'receipt' => "R13D13"),
    array('product_id' => 5, 'receipt' => "Y28Z14"),
    array('product_id' => 7, 'receipt' => "R02310"),
    array('product_id' => 5, 'receipt' => "E11403")
);

$result = [];
foreach($purchases as $key => $purchase) {
    if (!isset($result[$purchase["product_id"]])) {
        $result[$purchase["product_id"]] = $purchase;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [7] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 7
            [receipt] => R13D13
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [receipt] => Y28Z14
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/mqkLH)